# Why do I receive 2 mediaStreams while adding track to a peer in webRTC?

Tags: javascript, webrtc, simple-peer

I am given to understand that `RTCPeerConnection.addStream()` is deprecated and instead `addTrack()` should be used in its place. However this causes the server to add two `tracks` ( audio and video ) hence I receieve 2 `mediaStream` at my client side.

Is one of these `mediaStreams` enough? Is there a way to send only 1 `stream` back?

This is a part of my code :

server :

```
 filteredOne.forEach((el, index) => { //! incStream has the stream ID for identification
        foundGuest.tracks.forEach(t => peer[el.id].addTrack(t, foundGuest.incStream) && console.log('track added to other peer'))
        el.tracks && el.tracks.forEach(t => peer[id].addTrack(t, el.incStream) && console.log('track added to self peer'))
```

And client :

```
peer.ontrack = (e) => {
          console.log('e' , e.streams[0].id)
```

in which I receive 2 `e.streams[0].id` with same value.

Answer (score 3):

This happens when your MediaStream has two tracks, one for audio, the other for video. The `e.track` in the track event will be different. The e.streams[0].id is the same because they belong to the same MediaStream.